# need to pass an id from table in laravel to script in another blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

This is **single.blade.php**

```
@foreach($device_property_List as $val)
<tr>
    <td>{{$val -> properties-> number_plate}}</td>                            

    <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$val -> id}}"> <-this value need to pass in single_device.blade.php by ajax
        <input type="submit" id="{{$val -> id}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm live" value="Live">
    </td>

    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This is the script of this page(**single.blade.php**) to send the id to another page (**single_device.blade.php**)

This is **single.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.live', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({    
        window.location.href ="{{url('single_device')}} ->with (id)";              
    })
}); 
</script>
```

I need to get the id value in this blade inside this script (**single_device.blade.php**)

This is **single_device.blade.php**

```
<main class="main">
    <div id='map'></div>
</main>
<script>
var device_id = (here i need that id)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to familiarize yourself with what ajax is

and I think a link solves your problem.

```
<a href="{{route('single_device', ['id' => 1])}}">Some Text</a>
```

or

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".live").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        /* the route pointing to the update function */
                        url: '/',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {id:$(this).val()},
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        /* remind that 'data' is the response of the Controller */
                        success: function (data) {

                        }
                    }); 
                });
           });    
</script>
```

Comment: yes its fine but i was trying to avoid passing id in url

Comment: Hi, Can we pass the data without showing the value in the Url ? because we passing Device id, we want to show that in public Url

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store id in session using ajax request and then call in a blade where you want.
2. The other way is,to use encrypted and decrypted id in url.

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
   $key = Crypt::encrypt($key);

   <a href="{{route('single_device', ['id' => $key])}}">Some Text</a>
   $key = Crypt::decrypt($key);
   ```